# ASP.NET MVC 3. I need to worry about Container Dispose?

Tags: inversion-of-control, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, dispose

At ASP.NET MVC, I need to Dispose explicitly(As said here http://unity.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=38588) my Container, to objects inside it be Disposed.

With ASP.NET MVC 3 and native IoC support, I still need to worry about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With ASP.NET MVC 3 and native IoC support, I still need to worry about it?

Yes, you still need to worry about it if you are using a third party object container framework such as Unity which manages the lifetime of your objects. But to be 100% sure put a breakpoint in your Dispose method and see if it gets called at the end of the request.

Comment: Assuming those objects actually need to be disposed at the end of the request, rather than at the end of the app.